# How to select data according to the parameters of a column MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to build in PHP a module with google maps, I have a database in MySql with a list of 20 locations and a column called pos, which allows me to establish which position each location goes to.

I need to define these three elements, ** ORIGIN **, ** DESTINATION ** and ** WAYPOINTS **, ** origin ** would be ** pos 1 **, ** destination pos 20 ** and the ** waypoints * * between ** pos 2 and 19 **.

BD

```
id | pos | r_lat  | r_lng    | placa  | r_ruta  | jornada |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 05  | 6.4445 | -75.5512 | TTY541 | Comfama | B       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 2 | 01  | 6.3517 | -75.3512 | TTY541 | Comfama | B       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 3 | 18  | 6.3511 | -75.3475 | TTY541 | Comfama | B       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 4 | 20  | 6.3488 | -75.3342 | TTY541 | Comfama | B       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
 5 | 11  | 6.3425 | -75.3408 | TTY541 | Comfama | B       |
......
```

PHP script

```
$ruta = $_GET['ruta'];
$jornada = $_GET['jornada'];
$placa_id = $_SESSION[ 'usr_name' ];

    $query_users = "SELECT * FROM escolar WHERE placa='$placa_id' AND r_ruta='$ruta' AND jornada='$jornada'";
    $users = mysqli_query( $con, $query_users );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users);

    $pos = $row["pos"];
```

JavaScript

```
 source = new google.maps.LatLng(
    <?php
    if($pos == "1"){
        echo $row['r_lat'];
        echo ',';
        echo $row['r_lng'];
    }?>);
destination = new google.maps.LatLng(
    <?php
    if($pos == "20"){
        echo $row['r_lat'];
        echo ',';
        echo $row['r_lng'];
    }?>);
```

But it does not work for me, I could not load the data. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm a PHP student, any help is very useful, Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is i cant get all data from pos column, for to can select any pos. yo creo que no estoy llamando bien los datos `$pos = $row["pos"];` only show me the first data in the list: pos 05

Comment: `and a column called pos, which allows me to establish which position each location goes to` - why doesn't id do that?

Comment: Also, note that you are open to sql injection attack.

Comment: because those positions are stopped, and stops can be modified from a form; one day pos 9 can be programmed as pos 11 and so

Comment: Ok, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query